# How can I view the data I retrieved from my .SQLITE database in my debug area using the NSLog command?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode4.2

Whenever when I press build, it would give me the SIGABORT sign and goes back to the code.
Do I need a usable storyboard view or without it I could see the output in the Debug Area

The code I used was

```
for (PokemonAbility *theability in items) {

 NSLog(@"Number: %@  Name: %@ Generation: %@ Desc: %@",theability.rowid, theability.abilityname, theability.abilitygeneration, theability.abilitydesc);

 }
```

Referenced from:
[Code Reference](http://kurrytran.blogspot.com/2011/08/ios-5-tutorial-part-i-sqlite.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hard to tell from what you wrote, but I bet that you're using raw data from SQLite, which is a C string, and using it in NSLog as an NSString.  Try

```
[NSString stringWithCString:theability.rowid];
```

etc.